# WPF & MVVM - Close Window from within Child control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, controls

I need to close a modal window from a ViewModel based on a click command that is triggered in a control that is presented within the window.

So, I have MainViewModel, JimViewModel, JimWindow and JimControl. MainViewModel creates a JimWindow and sets its DataContext to JimViewModel. JimWindow contains JimControl, which contains a button. When this button is clicked, I'd like to trigger a command that somehow closes JimWindow.

I've seen a few questions that answer this with respect to closing the Window from the actual Window (By passing the instance of the Window to a Command on the ViewModel), but it doesn't translate to what I want to do.

I'm not using a framework so I have no handy messenger to assist me. Can anyone help? Is it a case of somehow referencing the Name of the parent window from the control?

Comment: Since the window closing is strictly view-related, I would say overriding the event to call the command (if necessary) and close the window is better than the view model providing that functionality within the command.

Comment: Where would this call to close be, though? The button that closes the window is in the control that sits inside the window. Should the window pass a reference to itself to the control?

Comment: The function would be overridden within the context of the window already. That is, the overriding class would be the window and could thus just call `Close()`. This adds code to a place where code should be scarce, but I don't think it's code that belongs in the VM. I don't have enough experience to know all other options available.

Answer (score 1):

`MainViewModel` should not be creating windows, at least not directly. VMs should only create VMs. A window is part of the view world.

If you need your `JimVM` hosted in a window, then it would be better to have some kind of `WindowService` abstracted away behind an interface. `MainVM` then just creates `JimVM` and gives it to the window service to host in a window

Once you've got the windows bit decoupled into a separate service, then you can do all your crufty window stuff in there. I would have `JimVM` expose a `CloseCommand` and a `Closed` event. You can bind your `JimControl` button to the `CloseCommand`, and the windows service can subscribe to the `Close` event, and tear down the window when it fires.

This keeps the view and VM stuff completely separate. The only thing that knows how to glue the two together is the window manager.

Answer (score 0):

Although idea of `ViewModel` creating a `View` sounds a little backwards, you could use messaging, e.g. [TinyMessenger](https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyMessenger) or Messenger that comes with [MVVMLight](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLightLibs/).

You could then register for a message in your View/ViewModel and send it from-anywhere. A really simplistic example using MVVMLight could be:

```
// custom message
public class CloseMessage : MessageBase
{
    public CloseMessage(object sender)
        :base(sender)
    {}
}
```

---

```
// main view registers for a message
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<CloseMessage>(this, message =>
        {
            // do teh stuff
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

---

```
// command bound to close button sends the message
private void YourCloseMainViewCommand()
{
    Messenger.Default.Send(new CloseMessage(this));
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I don't really know much about Messenger classes. Would JimWindow be created as an instance in my MainWindow (or rather, MainControl in my case) class?

Comment: It doesn't even matter. You can register/send messages where ever you need to.

Comment: Actually I have an old repo set up demonstrating MVVM Messaging at https://github.com/mikkoviitala/cross-viewmodel-communication if you want to take a peek.

Comment: I'll have a browse, cheers. I'm limited in what I can use in terms of external classes though.

Comment: There's many libraries, from Microsoft and 3rd parties, that make MVVM implementation that much faster, cleaner and enjoyable. Not using any would be foolish and waste of money/energy :)

Comment: I know, Mikko - unfortunately it's not my decision! Cheers for your help.